# Settling time of DAQ 6229

Tags: datasheet, data-acquisition

i have NI 6229 DAQ and datasheet and i come up across the settling time versus time for different source impedances [image]

i would know how is settling time calculated? i was thinking a simple RC network and the settling time is the time that the capacitor take to fully charge depanding in the source resistance and then i come up across the settling time for multichannel measurements 
[image]
i would like to know how is the values of settling time calculated and for what source resistance since i can't find it in the graph

thank you

Comment: The source resistance \$\color{red}{\text{is}}\$ shown in the graph.

Comment: but how to calculate the capacitor for example for source impedance of 5Kohm

Comment: Dunno, don't know what data sheet you used.

Comment: i used  NI 6229 DAQ data sheet